# Kotlin equivalent of Swift string enum (typed set of string constants)

Tags: swift, enums, kotlin

I have the following Swift enum:

```
enum ScreenName: String {
    case start = "Start Screen"
    case dashboard = "My Dashboard Screen"
}
```

Which allows me to have a typed set of constants and use them like:

```
func trackView(screen: ScreenName) {
     print("viewed \(screen.rawValue)")
}

trackView(screen: .start) // -> "viewed Start Screen"
```

What would be the equivalent of this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

something like:

```
enum class ScreenName(val displayName : String) { 
  START("Start Screen"), 
  DASHBOARD("My Dashboard Screen") 
}

fun trackView(screenName : ScreenName) {
  print("viewed ${screenName.displayName}")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility which I have discovered now, is with a sealed class:

```
sealed class ScreenName(val name : String) {
    object Start :     ScreenName("Start Screen")
    object Dashboard : ScreenName("My Dashboard Screen")

    data class NewsDetail(val title: String) : ScreenName("News")

    val displayName: String
        get() = when(this) {
            is NewsDetail -> "${name} - ${title}"
            else -> name
        }
}
```

This has the advantage that it can mimic Swift enums with associated values.

Comment: Typed enums are not enums with associated values, those are different concepts. The Swift example in the OP is using enums where the values *are* strings, while an associated string value is still an int like every normal enum with it has a string value *associated* with it.